# Can you tamper with the cookie expiration date of a signed cookie in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

As far as I'm aware, once a cookie is sent as a response (and the cookie includes an expiration date), the expiration date is not sent back with the request, just the cookie content.

Thus, even if a cookie is signed in Rails, is it possible to just tamper with its expiration date and set it way far in the future than it actually is?

Comment: You can provide a secure value via `cookies.encrypted[:valid_until] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to only tamper with a cookie's expiration date for an encrypted/signed cookie, unless you provide additional security.

Seeing how the value is encrypted anyway, you could always add additional information to the cookie value - eg. the expiration date (and store the entire value in an array form, with element index 0 being the value and element index 1 being the cookie expiration date, for instance, or use some query within that string and split the string to get the value). Then, in your controller, parse the cookie value into an array and check the value of expiration date (eg if it should've already expired, in that case raise an error) and set the cookie's expiration date back to the correct, non-tampered value for the client. That way, every time you require a value of that cookie, you can always check whether the cookie should still even be present or whether the expiration date had been tampered with.

I should think you needn't do this often and the application of it is for a quite specific controller method. It's a hackish way, sure, but it's the only way to be really sure both the cookie value and the cookie expiration date hadn't been tampered with.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you surely can.

cookies.signed[:ssid] = { value: '', expires: Time.now + ***30.minutes*** } OR
cookies.signed[:ssid] = { value: '', expires: Time.now + ***60.years*** }

Here value can be a string or an array.
With this you can set the cookie expiry as far in the future you want.

Comment: This does not answer the question, the question is about already set cookies. The method you are explaining is for new cookies only in rails code.